# Django update table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
obj = Info(name= sub,question=response_dict["question"])
obj.save()
```

After saving the data how to update another field of the same table

```
obj.err_flag=1
obj.update()//Will this work
```

Comment: when you say 'another field of the same table' do you mean 'another field of the same object'? The answer would be different depending on what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just resave that instance:

```
obj.some_field = some_var
obj.save()
```

Django automatically knows when to `UPDATE` vs. `INSERT` your instance in the database.
This is explained in the 
[Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert).

Answer (score 3):

```
obj = Info(name=sub,question=response_dict["question"])
obj.save()
```

And then later you want to get it and update it (I'm assuming name is unique identifier):

```
obj = Info.objects.get(name=sub)
obj.err_flag=1
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

If in the question you mean to say `same object` or `same row` where you say `same table`, then if you do this

```
obj = Info(name= sub,question=response_dict["question"])
obj.save()
```

and then after a few lines you need to do this

```
obj = Info.objects.get(name=sub)
obj.err_flag=1
obj.save()
```

then `obj = Info.objects.get(name=sub)` is unnecessary.

You simply do

```
obj = Info(name= sub,question=response_dict["question"])
obj.save()
#
#do what you want to do, check what you want to check
#
obj.err_flag=1
obj.save()
```